# How to use multiple DB connections using .env in Lumen 5.5..?

Tags: php, eloquent, lumen-5.5

I have installed Lumen 5.5 and configured .env :

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=2gh4RD89kWa87clEs6Vhjso3XhsFo3dR
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=XXXXXX
DB_USERNAME=XXXXXX
DB_PASSWORD=XXXXXX

CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

and created a model using Eloquent :

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model {
    
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $connection = 'foo';
}
```

Now there is no documention on the official site to configure multiple DB connection in `.env` file. My single connection is working perfectly fine but now I need to add another DB connection details.

What I have tried so far :

1. Created db config file as `app/config/database.php` with multiple db details but my setup doesn't get affected whatever i write in that file. It's only using `.env` to get connection details.
2. Tried to add multiple DB connection details in `.env` file like :

   DB_CONNECTION=mysql
   DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
   DB_PORT=3306
   DB_DATABASE=XXXXXX
   DB_USERNAME=XXXXXX
   DB_PASSWORD=XXXXXX

   FOO_DB_CONNECTION=mysql
   FOO_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
   FOO_DB_PORT=3306
   FOO_DB_DATABASE=FOOXXXXXX
   FOO_DB_USERNAME=FOOXXXXXX
   FOO_DB_PASSWORD=FOOXXXXXX

   DB_CONNECTION_FOO=mysql
   DB_HOST_FOO=127.0.0.1
   DB_PORT_FOO=3306
   DB_DATABASE_FOO=FOOXXXXXX
   DB_USERNAME_FOO=FOOXXXXXX
   DB_PASSWORD_FOO=FOOXXXXXX

But it just keep giving me this error :

```
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Database [foo] not configured.
```

I have tried everything I found on Google.

Comment: Show your database config file. Of course remove sensitive data.

Comment: he added env details, not the database configuration details. @Ritesh please post your database.php

Comment: As i have mentioned in my question, config/database.php is not working for me. Either i create this file or not.. my project running same.

Comment: @ayip any solution..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I configured in my project (it is in Lumen 5.4) is as below:

in the `config/database.php`

```
'pgsql' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'db'),
        'port'     => env('DB_PORT', 5432),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'service_db'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'service_user'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'  => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
        'prefix'   => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
        'schema'   => env('DB_SCHEMA', 'public'),
    ],

    'pgsql2' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST2', 'db'),
        'port'     => env('DB_PORT', 5432),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE2', 'service_db'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME2', 'service_user'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD2'),
        'charset'  => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
        'prefix'   => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
        'schema'   => env('DB_SCHEMA2', 'public'),
    ],
```

I have created 2 connections with 2 different names and each connection points to a different env variable for db host/database/username/password/schema. If this doesn't help, post your database.php file.

Comment: Silly mistake i've done.. was placed the config folder inside app folder.. moving out of app folder worked..!!  thanks..!!